# How can I deprecate flash/flex exposed javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, externalinterface

We developed a flex component that now it's used by several web applications.
We found that some callbacks are old and they have bad arguments.
For example when they are used to set some param they take one object, while when they get the same param they use another object.
We would like to make these functions to be coherent in setting and getting parameters.
So we thought to start developing new getters and setters about them with new names and the right parameters. 
Anyway, since the component is used by many other applications we cannot rename the callbacks, neither change their implementation, we could have problems with the other web apps. 
So we would like to know if there is some way to make flash exposed callbacks deprecated, so that people that are using these methods will see some warnings and will start to substitute with the not deprecated version.
Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 4):

Once an API, always an API.

You can't just remove stuff from the API or else the apps that currently use those commands will fail. Just add new replacement API and keep the old ones. State in the docs that the old ones are deprecated and there is a better command for it.

An example of this is jQuery's `live()` and `delegate()` which was replaced by `on()`. Although deprecated, `live()` and `delegate()` still exist on 1.7 to accommodate old API especially to those who upgraded the library but use an outdated, unmaintained plugin.

---

You could also do it like this. You can reveal the same interface for the old API but underneath it, it uses the new APIs implementation but with a bit of modification. That way, you won't be repeating your code.

For example, let's take jQuery `delegate()`, `live()` and `on()`. These aren't the actual codes of these methods, but I'm after the concept of deprecation (I can't think of other examples for deprecation other than `delegate()`, `live()` and `on()`).

```
//the three have different set-ups
.live(event,callback);
.delegate(selector,event,callback);
.on(event,selector,callback);

//to avoid multiple underlying implementations
//you can "map" the old API to use the new API's implementation
//while maintaining the old interface and functionality
live = function(event,callback){
    $(document).on(event,callback);
}
delegate = function(selector,event,callback){
    $(this).on(event,selector,callback);
}

//the new implementation as used by on
on = function(event,selector,callback){
    //implementation
}
```

Comment: So, as we thought there isn't a proper way to do that, except writing it in the documentation. I will wait to see if there are some creative ideas, to gather automatically deprecations. Thank you

Comment: Interesting comparison with jQuery! I guess you could consider logging a warning to the browser console to inform those who don't RTFM that the method is now deprecated.

Comment: Well, i think your idea is quite good, but i needed the information because the function should return a different object, so i cannot hide new functions inside legacy methods. Anyway, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Few things that are not clear:

1. Who is building the Flash side of the code? The people who use the component, or do they get it compiled and have no idea of what's inside?
2. How savvy in general the audience is?
3. What is the general life time of the applications been built using the component. Did you make your version policies explicit?

**IMO:** *(meaning that this is just my opinion, not an absolute truth, this approach is more typical for Linux development, but scary / untypical for Windows for example).*

Now, if your users are building your code, I'd say go straight for `[Deprecated()]` meta for 2-3 minor version releases and drop it after that, certainly don't drag it into a major version release. It's good to give some support for older version, and, possibly, release patches, if you have a bandwidth for it, but improving is more important. Certain tactics may help. For example, if the users were exposed to beta products, they will be more likely to adopt the change faster.

If your audience is mostly savvy / have good community communications, probably a single minor version would suffice - worst case there would be few left behind with the old compatible version. Again, it's good if you have patches for old version, but you will bind your hands by keeping to the wrong API and after some time due to that API your users will regard your application as an outdated crap, which locks them into using things they would rather change.

It is very important to only promise consistency between minor versions. Of course, it is a good thing if you can keep backwards compatible several versions back, but this is a bonus rather than requirement. While on the surface of it other people using your product might be reluctant to adopt the change, the other option is still worse. There should be some reasonable amount of time, that fits the average application life time for you to provide support. Something that wouldn't make an average application obsolete before it is even useful, but all things in moderation.

Comment: Well, you partially answered my question, but I think at the end your opinion is useful. I will answer to your question: 1. I'm building the flex code and other people should use it through javascript API. 2. The audience is made by programmers. 3. The lifetime of the applications is not little, by now the component has been used since 2009, anyway I didn't make the initial version of it, but i had to change that component in the past and i developed several features.